# How to Center Radio Button

Tags: html, css, radio-button, flexbox, centering

For my webpage I am using radio buttons to make tabs with content on the top of my webpage. I want the tabs to be centered in the screen. I tried to use display: flex and text-align: justify but it didn't work. Is there a simple way to center the radio buttons? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the HTML

```
<body>
<div class="allTabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
      <div class="content">
         stuff 1
      </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
    <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>  
    <div class="content">
       stuff 2
    </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
    <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
    <div class="content">
       stuff 3
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.tabs {   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: white; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 4px solid #DADEDE;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mk8r6kL0/

Comment: have you tried margin-left and right:auto;?

Comment: yes but sadly it didn't do anything

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mk8r6kL0/3/ i wasn't sure where you wanted aligned

Comment: First be aware that in your CSS you add style to the `.tabs` class which doesn't appear to exist.  Did you mean the `.allTabs` class?

Comment: Yep it is aligned fine. Thanks!

Comment: 0hhh. that explains a lot :)

Comment: @Noobie123 thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/mk8r6kL0/2/)

Remove `float:left;` from your CSS for `.tab` and add `display:inline-block;`

Also, add

```
.allTabs {
    text-align: center;
}
```

to your CSS

So, the complete CSS would be as below

```
.allTabs {
    text-align: center;
}
.tabs {
    min-height: 200px;
    clear: both;
}
.tab {
    display: inline-block;
}
.tab label {
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
}
.tab[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 4px solid #DADEDE;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    background: white;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @Noobie123 ..:)

Comment: oh. now i think i fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Remove the floats and try...

```
.allTabs {
    text-align: center;
}

.tab {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mk8r6kL0/4/)